Please identify this 80's/90's Ghost style movie
I have a few fragments from a scene of a movie rattling around in my head, so I hope this comes across as coherent.
The movie had a Ghost (Swayze) feel to it. It was either set in the very late 80's or early 90's. The scene I am picturing is of a young boy (12/13) with a baseball cap on standing in front of a large black lady at a Train station ticket office. I think the ticket office was outside on the street, the city looked to be New York. The scene involved talks of supernatural occurrences.
This is all I can remember! If anyone can help, that would be great! 

I'm assuming you're not thinking of the Sixth Sense?

@DisgruntledGoat No, definitely not the Sixth Sense.

Was the boy the ghost?  Was the woman the ghost?  Not sure?  And what do you mean by Ghost feel to it?  Like an unfinished business sort of way or a not scary kind of way?

@drneel Being very helpful, i'm not sure. The woman wasn't a ghost but i think people thought the boy was a ghost but he wasn't. This was a topic of the conversation between the woman and boy. Just the supernatural element

Have you tried this yet? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ghost_films  It's a long list but... good chance it's in there ;)

I know this seems really off from what you remember but is there a chance that it might be The Crow? There is a scene in the middle of the movie where the teenage girl (who looks kind of tomboyish and has a gravelly voice) is talking to Ernie Hudson at a hot dog stand. I'm trying to find a piece of video to link show you.
